# How to highlight part of a string

Tags: front-end, boxes

The following two works:

```
highlighted1="\*StyleBox[\""<>#<>"\",Background->RGBColor[1,1,0]]"&;

highlighted2="\*TemplateBox[{\""<>#<>"\",FrameStyle->None},\"Highlighted\"]"&;
```

`highlighted1` doesnot highlight the entire height of the sentence while `highlighted2` does highlight the entire height but leaves a space between the highlighted and the unhighlighted even when they are part of the same word.

Can you please help me find a fix here such that i have highlighting like in `highlighted2` but no spaces like in `highlighted1`.

`"where are "<>highlighted1@"y"<>"ou"<>" going"`

`"where are "<>highlighted2@"y"<>"ou"<>" going"`

Comment: Does adding `,FrameMargins->{{-1,-1},{0,0}}` to `highlighted2` achieve what you're after?

Comment: Yes thanks Lukas, it works for me.